# Reading a file in Servlet program

Tags: java, file, servlets

I am trying to understand what is the correct way to read a file in Java Servlet program. I need to read a file from a fixed path on my machine using my servlet code. Now I can read the file in multiple ways and one of the way which I am planning to use is to read the information in bytes as shown in below code:

```
private static void readFile(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, String path)
    throws IOException
  {
    File file = new File("C:\\temp\", path);

    if (!file.isFile()) {
      resp.sendError(404, "File not found: " + file);
      return;
    }
    InputStream in = null;
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {
      resp.setContentLength(Long.valueOf(file.length()).intValue());
      resp.resetBuffer();
      out = resp.getOutputStream();
      in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
      readFile(in, out);
    }
    finally {
     //Code for closing the input & output steams
      }
    }
  }

 public static void readFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
  {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int data;
    while ((data = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1)
      out.write(buf, 0, data);
  }
```

I don't have issues with this logic and it is working fine.

Now I came across the post [How To Read File In Java – BufferedReader](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) in mykyong site and here the example uses `BufferedReader`.

Can someone please tell me which is the efficient way of reading a file in servlet code? when we need to prefer using `BufferedReader` in comparison to reading data in bytes.

Comment: type and size of file does matter. As of Java 7 there's new File I/O API - nio2, so you might want to check out that as well.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to revise working code based on some arbitrary Internet blog. You should want a much more authoritative source than that to even consider it, and some readily identifiable benefit. There is none here. The fact that you're in a Servlet makes zero difference. You shouldn't use `Readers` unless you know the file to be text and you want to actually process it as such. Otherwise you should use `InputStream` and `OutputStream` as you are doing, or the Java 7 NIO2 APIs.

Comment: @EJP I was also checking at the SO post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728953/reading-and-writing-from-text-file-in-servlet where the program also uses BufferedReader, so I wanted to confirm if I am following right approach or not. But thank a lot to SO, as I came to know about the new feature for reading files in Java 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's almost no reason to read a file manually anymore since Java 7's NIO.

Just use [`Files.readAllBytes(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to read the full `byte[]`. Or if you want to stream directly to an `OutputStream`, [`Files.copy(Path, OutputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

> Can someone please tell me which is the efficient way of reading a
>   file in servlet code? when we need to prefer using BufferedReader in
>   comparison to reading data in bytes.

Any buffered method will work. Here, [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) allows you to read streams as `String` values. As the javadoc says

> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as
>   to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.